# Metal catalysts used in C-H bond functionalisation

Tags: transition-metals, catalysis

Why are the late transition metals used for C-H bond activation/functionalisation? What atomic properties of the late TM make them attractive for coordinating C-H sigma bonds? 
Thanks.